# How to change default PDF viewer on Nook Color?

Tags: pdf, nook-color

- I just upgraded my **Nook Color** to the
  new **1.2 version that supports apps**.
- I purchased the **ezPDF Reader** app
  which supports bookmarks and other
  advanced features for PDFs which the
  default Nook Color PDF viewer does
  not support.

**Is there a way to make the ezPDF Reader the default PDF Viewer?**

(Currently when I click on a PDF the default viewer still opens)

**To Clarify:**
Currently I have to open the ezPDF Reader first and then open a PDF from within the app. If I simply click on a PDF on a book shelf or on the home screen then the default PDF viewer opens the PDF. I don't see any area in settings like on a regular Android phone to modify installed apps or app settings.

Comment: I didn't know the Nook ran Android.

Comment: Yes it does. The latest version is on Android OS 2.2/Froyo.

Comment: @KevinM Yep, I flashed CM7 on my a while back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest update of the Nook Color software  **Version 1.4.1** allows you to change the default PDF reader. After the upgrade open a PDF and then a pop up box will appear allowing you to choose which application you want as the default PDF reader.

Answer (score 2):

Find the app that took over the PDF intent in `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All`, and then tap on `Clear defaults` button.  Next time you click on a PDF file, it should prompt you which app to use.  Check the `Use by default for this action` box, and tap on ezPDF Reader.

Alternatively, you can try uninstalling and re-installing the ezPDF Reader app.  It should re-register its own intent for handling PDFs, and prompt you for an app next time you try to view one.

Comment: This works on a Nook Color which is not rooted?

Comment: @KenB: it's a fairly standard way to clear defaults on Android phones, unless Nook was modified so this won't work for no reason this should work.

Comment: Yes, Nook Color is a custom / modified version of the Android OS. I don't believe you can access the application settings (as was described above) like you would on a standard Android device. Has anyone tried this on a Nook Color with the version 1.2 update?

Comment: I'm running CM7 on my NC, so I had no idea they disabled application management tools in stock firmware.  What about uninstalling/re-installing your PDF reader app? That *should* register its intent and allow you to select it as the default.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't seem to work. I still have to open the ezPDF Reader first and then open a PDF from within the app. If I simply click on a PDF on a book shelf or on the home screen then the default PDF viewer opens the PDF. I don't see any area in settings like on a regular Android phone to modify installed apps or app settings.

Comment: The above suggested changes using the setting menu do not have a way of working. Will not work even in Nook Color 1.3.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

There is an app for that !! Try Default App Manager on the Android Market which can take care of both clearing and setting defaults for various categories like pictures, audio, video, pdf etc. Really makes life very easy.